# Apycom Jquery menu not working fine

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I am using Apycom jQuery Menus which is available at this link

```
http://apycom.com/ source link
```

My menu was working find but suddenly it begain to create problem as shown in image, When i move my mouse on one of then menu link it works fine but on load it doesn't load menu correctly.
[image]

Comment: Hi Rizwan, please post some css/html/javascript code which you are trying with

Comment: @tusar as i have mentioned the link where i did download.